# Entity Framework Select Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class Seller : Entity
{
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<InventoryItem> InventoryItems { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryItem : Entity
{
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public string SellerSku { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SiteInventoryItem> SiteInventoryItems { get; set; }
}

public class SiteInventoryItem : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    public SiteType Site { get; set; }
}
```

So a `Seller` has a collection of `InventoryItem` which in turn have a collection of `SiteInventoryItem`.

How do I get a `Seller` with a list of `InventoryItems` that have a list of `SiteInventoryItems` where the `SiteType == SiteType.SiteName` and the `Seller.SellerId == 14`?

The `SiteType` is an `Enum` and the db type is `int`.

I have tried the following and it compiles and runs, but the result is not what is expected:

```
var seller = repo.Query(
                x => x.InventoryItems,
                x => x.InventoryItems.Select(y => y.SiteInventoryItems)
            ).Select(x => new
            {
                Seller = x,
                InventoryItems = x.InventoryItems,
                SiteInventoryItems = x.InventoryItems.Select(y => new
                {
                    InventoryItem = y,
                    SiteInventoryItems = y.SiteInventoryItems.Where(z => z.Site == SiteType.Amazon)
                })
            }).Where(x => x.Seller.SellerId == 14).First();
```

Comment: You need a `Seller` that its `InventoryItems` collection contain at least one `InventoryItem` that is having at least one `SiteInventoryItem` with the appropriate value?

Comment: @haim770 - I need a `Seller` with a collection of `InventoryItem` and then each of those have a collection of `SiteInventoryItem` with the constraints being `Seller.SellerId == 14` and `SiteInventoryItem.Site == 1`

Comment: What does "no luck at all" mean? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it return results?

Comment: @CodeCaster - It compiles and runs, but the result is not what is expected.

Comment: What do you expect and what is the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var seller = repo.Query()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Seller = x,
            InventoryItems = x.InventoryItems.Select(y => new
            {
                InventoryItem = y,
                SiteInventoryItems = y.SiteInventoryItems.Where(z => z.Site == SiteType.Amazon)
            }).Where(y => y.SiteInventoryItems.Any())
        }).Where(x => x.Seller.Id == 14).First();
```

I've restructured the result type a bit, because I think it makes more sense this way. Now you see that the result only returns `Seller`s that have `InventoryItems` that have `SiteInventoryItems`.

Note that I also removed the arguments for `repo.Query()`. I assume that they serve as `Include`s. But I also hope that `repo.Query()` returns an `IQueryable`, so that the `Where` clause will be translated into the generated SQL. If so, the `Include`s are useless, because you're already querying the included entities because they are part of the anonymous type.

Comment: This stills returns all of the `InventoryItem` regardless of if they have a `SiteInventoryItem` or not.

Comment: I see, the condition should be one level deeper (the naming is a bit elusive).

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: Does not even compile now.

Comment: Well, I haven't got your code. Probably some parentheses somewhere. I have to do this by eyesight only. Feel free to modify my answer.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer, you were super close and it got me going in the right direction, Thanks for your efforts!!